# Installing OpenSUSE - Cannot format partitions

Tags: partition, system-installation, opensuse

I'll make this fast. OpenSUSE is throwing up a whole bunch of errors when I try to install it. I am 90% sure that the partitions I set up are correct, but the installer doesn't seem impressed by my efforts. The error messages I got can be found here:

The Before and After labels indicate the partition setup that I ATTEMPTED to create:
[image: Before]
[image: After]
[image: failure setting disk label]
[image: failure setting disk label]
[image: failure mounting sdb3]
[image: failure mounting sdb1]
[image: failure mounting sdb2]
[image: failure formatting sdb3]
[image: failure formatting sdb2]
[image: failure formatting sdb1]
[image: failure creating volume sdb3]
[image: failure creating volume sdb2]
[image: error occurred during initrd creation]

The phrase "unrecognised disk label" keeps coming up. Did I skip a step? I thought that labels were optional?

Oddly, Gparted does not seem to agree with SUSE on the disk's contents. This concerns me.

[image: gparted sdb]
[image: gparted sda]
[image: partition list]

Additional info:

```
user@debian~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit s print 
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 234441648s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number Start End Size Type File system Flags
```

Comment: so you have to disks sda and sdb but sdb is the one with troubles?... Did you check if the drive is ok... ¿badblocks?

Comment: Yes, sda is a 2TB HDD and sdb is a 120GB SDD. Both drives worked just fine last week. The SSD is less than a year old, so I can't imagine it going bad already.

Comment: They both seem to be acting oddly though. sda seems to sprout a set of Linux partitions while sdb is left with nothing. Could the installer be trying to write the OS onto sda even though the partitions were set up on sdb?

Comment: No. That's not it. Removing the HDD didn't change the result at all. So now I have an SSD that refuses to be formatted.

Comment: Tried the same thing with Debian. Got similar results.
"The ext4 file system partition creation in partition #2 of SCSI1 (0, 1, 0) (sda) failed"

Comment: maybe is best if you want to install the OS on sbd to do a `dd` on that HDD first to clean the partition table.

Comment: That's a good idea. I have done this now. Used "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc" That didn't do anything noticeable. Followed that up with "dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb". Still nothing. I am immediately told that I have an "unrecognised disk label"

Comment: Interestingly, the Win10 preview will reinstall with no fuss. So at least I know that the SSD isn't bricked.

Comment: mmmm did you check the .iso? maybe is wrong.

Comment: I checked the Mint iso, but I did not check the Debian one. That would require both isos to be bad. I will try again later today.

Comment: Okay, I double checked both discs and they came up clean.

Comment: I decided to take another swing at this. Booted up Gparted and wiped the entire drive. Then I ran "badblocks -wsv -o /root/badblocks.txt /dev/sdb". It checked the disc 4 times and all of them came up clean. So there are no bad blocks on the drive. I am at a loss now.

Comment: After you wiped the entire drive and run badblock does not work? http://gparted-forum.surf4.info/viewtopic.php?id=17251

Answer (score 0):

Is the partition unallocated? Because from the picture in the beginning,
where it says "Setting disk label of /dev/sdb to GPT" I think it's trying to give the hard disk an partition-table "GPT".

I'll suggest that try allocating the partition.

You could try the solution found from this link: [OpenSuse Support](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/402315-error-code-1014-when-installing-openSUSE-11-1)

1. Boot and run opensuse live.
2. Open up the Terminal.
3. Gain ROOT privileges.
4. List the disks with the "fdisk -l" command.
5. Then use cfdisk(8) and delete the space you want use for
   installation.